# Comparing Two strings with different order

Tags: java, string, compare

I am having a string of the form as

PosAttributes: FN,CT,ST;

Now when i compute some functionality i get a string as

PosAttributes1: FN,ST,CT;

Now though both the strings suggest the same thing and if use following equal function it returns false. I know both stings are not same, but the semantics are same. What should i do?

PosAttributes.equals(PosAttributes);

Comment: Is it possible that your string will contain duplicate attributes?  And if so, should strings with different duplicated values be treated as different?  For example, is `FN,ST,CT,CT` equal to `CT,FN,ST,ST`?

Answer (score 1):

As the string is delimitered by commas you could use a String.split to give

```
String arr[] = PosAttributes.split (",");
String arr2[] = PosAttributes1.split (",");
```

then you just need to loop through the first arrays ensuring that ALL elements are in the second array.  Also check that the sizes are identical.

Comment: can I make sure that the semantics are same in just one if statement?

Comment: Create a method that does this for you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to break out the individual sections of each String, and store them in some kind of Set - that's a structure where either there's no order, or where the order doesn't affect the outcome of the `equals` method.  I'd write a method like this.

```
private static Set<String> attributeSet(String input) {
    String[] attributes = input.split(",");
    return new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(attributes));
}
```

This breaks a String into its segments, assuming the separator is a comma.  Then it uses a standard trick to convert the resulting array into a `HashSet`, which is a commonly used type of `Set`.

Then when I want to compare two strings, I could write something like

```
if (attributeSet(string1).equals(attributeSet(string2))) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: This approach will only work if strings cannot contain duplicates. e.g. "FN, CT, ST, FN" is not a valid string. Otherwise that string will be considered equal to "FN, CT, ST". Up to OP whether this is a problem or not.

Comment: Yes, that's true.  Sounds like something that I should ask as a comment under the question.  Thank you @deyur.

Answer (score 0):

So assuming that the example text is the full text, you need to remove the `;` character, as this would change the contents of the `String`, split the `String` on the `,` character, sort the resulting arrays and compare them, something like...

```
String[] v1 = "FN,CT,ST;".replace(";", "").split(",");
String[] v2 = "FN,ST,CT;".replace(";", "").split(",");
Arrays.sort(v1);
Arrays.sort(v2);
System.out.println(Arrays.equals(v1, v2));
```

Which outputs `true`

What I might be tempted to do is write a method which returned a sorted array of the `String`, replicating all the common functionality...

```
public static String[] sorted(String value) {
    String[] v1 = value.replace(";", "").split(",");
    Arrays.sort(v1);
    return v1;
}
```

And then you could simply call it, which would allow you to do a single like comparison...

```
System.out.println(Arrays.equals(sorted("FN,CT,ST;"), sorted("FN,ST,CT;")));
```

The next step might be to write a method which returns `true`, which called `sorted` and `Arrays.equals` to make it easier...

```
System.out.println(isEqual("FN,CT,ST;", "FN,ST,CT;"));
```

But, I'll leave that up to you ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can either override the equal method or sort both string then compare them.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same requirement at work right now and wanted to avoid using lists for the evaluation.

What I did was to check if the two string to compare are of equal length - this means that it is possible that they might be the same, just with different order.

Now remove one by one comma-separated string in the main string, found in the compare string. If the output of the main string is empty, that means the two are an exact math. Please see the pseudo-code below (I did not paste the actual code because it has some company specific info):

```
private static boolean isStringCombinationEqual(final String main, final String compare)
{
    boolean result = false;
    String modifiedMain = main;

    // if not the same length, then cannot possibly be same combination in different order
    if (main.length() == compare.length())
    {
        final String[] compareArr = // split compare using delimiter

        for (int i = 0; i < compareArr.length; i++)
        {
            if (i > 0)
            {
                modifiedMain = // replace delimiter with empty string
            }

            modifiedMain = // replace compareArr[0] with empty string
        }

        if (//modifiedMain is empty)
        {
            result = true;
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```